# primefaces selectOneMenu how to reload

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I use 3 selectOneMenu components in my project. I need to reload content of the second after change in the first. Here are some parts of the files

index.xhtml

```
<h:form id="form">
<p:selectOneMenu id="Rząd" value="#{birdSelectorBean.selectedState}" effect="fade"
style="width: 150px;">  
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Rząd" itemValue="" />  
<f:selectItems value="#{birdSelectorBean.rzad}" />  
<p:ajax render="@form" listener="#{birdSelectorBean.stateChangeListener}" />
</p:selectOneMenu> 

<p:selectOneMenu id="rodzina" value="#{birdSelectorBean.selectedState}" effect="fade"
style="width: 150px;">  
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Rodzina" itemValue="" />
<f:selectItems value="#{birdSelectorBean.rodzina}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:selectOneMenu id="rodzaj" value="#{birdSelectorBean.selectedState}" effect="fade"
style="width: 150px;">  
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Rodzaj" itemValue="" />   
<f:selectItems value="#{birdSelectorBean.rodzaj}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

BirdSelectionBean.java:

```
public class BirdSelectorBean
{
private String selectedState;
private List<SelectItem> rzad;
private List<SelectItem> rodzina;
private List<SelectItem> rodzaj;

public BirdSelectorBean()
{
    rzad = new ArrayList<>();
    rzad.add(new SelectItem("Rząd_X"));
    rzad.add(new SelectItem("Rząd_Y"));
    rzad.add(new SelectItem("Rząd_Z"));

    rodzina = new ArrayList<>();
    rodzaj = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void stateChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent event)
{
    rodzina.clear();
    rodzina.add(new SelectItem("Rodzina_A"));
    rodzina.add(new SelectItem("Rodzina_B"));
    rodzina.add(new SelectItem("Rodzina_C"));
}
...
getters and setters
...
}
```

I read many topics on that but it doesn't work for me. I tried update="rodzina" like it is in example
[here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprSelect.jsf)
and render option like it is said in that
[topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641409/update-selectonemenu-if-value-of-ohter-selectonemenu-is-set-event-isnt-fired):
But it still doesn't work. Please help me :]

Answer (score 2):

In the `p:ajax` tag change `render="@form"` to `update="@form"`. Render is used by `f:ajax`, primefaces use another name for some reason - see [here](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/ajax.html).

Comment: That was the main point that caused the trouble so changing that helped me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `stateChangeListener` method nevers get called and more important, your managed bean looks like hasn't any scope (at least from your question content), remember that it must be at least `@ViewScoped` in order to make this work. Also, another problem in your code is that you're using the same attribute to select the data for the three `<p:selectOnuMenu>` (which is not a problem yet since you haven't achieved what you wanted to begin with).

To make the ajax update work, remove the parameter from your `stateChangeListener`. Also let's add the other two attributes for the selected items from the dropdownlists.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BirdSelectorBean {

    private String selectedState;
    private String selectedStateRodzina;
    private String selectedStateRodzaj;
    //other fields and methods...

    public void stateChangeListener() {
        rodzina.clear();
        rodzina.add(new SelectItem("Rodzina_A"));
        rodzina.add(new SelectItem("Rodzina_B"));
        rodzina.add(new SelectItem("Rodzina_C"));
    }
}
```

And then update your desired `<p:selectOneMenu>` in your `<p:ajax>` call (I removed the non-directly related to the problem attributes from the components like style):

```html
<p:selectOneMenu id="Rząd" value="#{birdSelectorBean.selectedState}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Rząd" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{birdSelectorBean.rzad}" />
    <p:ajax update="rodzina" listener="#{birdSelectorBean.stateChangeListener}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:selectOneMenu id="rodzina" value="#{birdSelectorBean.selectedStateRodzina}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Rodzina" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{birdSelectorBean.rodzina}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your help was helpful for me. I had bean configured in xml file. But you help me to straighten up my code.